# how to get values in K, M, B format- SQL query

Tags: sql

i want to get values in K, B, M format from the sql query. can cast function be used? if yes how can i get values using cast function

for example:

```
1,000 as 1K
1,000,000 as 1M
1,000,000,000 as 1B
etc.
```

Comment: if you use Postgres you can use the pg_size_pretty function

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `CASE WHEN` :

```
CASE WHEN Column_Name >= 1000 AND Column_Name < 1000000
    THEN CAST(Column_Name/1000 AS VARCHAR) + 'K'
     WHEN Column_Name >= 1000000 AND Column_Name < 1000000000
    THEN CAST(Column_Name/1000000 AS VARCHAR) + 'M'
     WHEN Column_Name >= 1000000000 AND Column_Name < 10000000000
    THEN CAST(Column_Name/1000000000 AS VARCHAR) + 'B'
    ELSE
      CAST(Column_Name AS VARCHAR)
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp

And

This: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-int/

In MySQL, There are `TINY INT` `SMALLINT` `MEDIUMINT` `INT` `BIGINT`.

Otherwise, you'd better cast them on your server. If you want to store them in different types in one column. That is not possible.

However, if you have three different columns and store them in it. You may try this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use format method like below. Each comma will reduce value by 1000

```
format(7000000,'$0,,M') will give output of $7M
```

You can make other format accordingly. For dynamically generation you may use `Case` Statement

Comment: For which DBMS is this answer?

Comment: SQL server database